# How to "order by ..." an Eloquent relationship using Builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, relationship, eloquent

I have to order a query, from a relationship in Laravel 4. There are two Models: `Task` and `Subproject`.

In `Task` I have a relationship with `Subproject`. This way:

```
public function subproject() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Subproject');
}
```

From my `Controller`, I want to order `Subproject` using `Laravel Builder` and not joins.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is is [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading). Load a model and it's linked model in a single request. You can do this with the `Eloquent::with()` method, like that :

```php
$subprojects = Subproject::with('task')->orderBy('subproject.id')->get();
```

Then you get a list of subprojects with, in memory, the linked tasks and you can call tasks without anymore SQL request :

```php
foreach($subprojects as $project) {
    echo $project->task->id;
}
```

Comment: guess I was'n clear. The relationship is right, but I want to order based on a parent table. Like that:

select subprojects.id, tasks.id from tasks 
join subprojects on tasks.subproject_id = subprojects.id
order by subprojects.id

Do you see the difference?

I do want to order by subprojects, but using `Eloquent` and not joins.

Thank you for the answer!

Comment: What kind of result do you need ? I think you want objects and not array or resultset like in a raw SQL Request. So I think the solution to your problem is eager loading (http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading). You can do something like : `$subprojects = Subproject::with('task')->orderBy('subproject.id')->get();` and get list of subprojects. Then you can call tasks like that : `foreach($subprojects as $project) echo $project->task->id;`

Comment: Yeah, guess I will do something like that. Thank you, Alexandre!

Comment: I have edited my answer to let a better explanation for the posterity ;)

Answer (score 1):

### From the comment :

> I want to order based on a parent table. Like that: **select
>   subprojects.id, tasks.id from tasks join subprojects on
>   tasks.subproject_id = subprojects.id order by subprojects.id**

It could be achived using following :

```
DB::table('tasks')
->join('subprojects', 'tasks.subproject_id', '=', 'subprojects.id')
->order_by('subprojects.id', 'ASC') // DESC
->select('subprojects.id,', 'tasks.id')
->get(); // for pagination you can use: ->paginate(5)
```